# current flow to vcc

Tags: microcontroller, theory

[image: Encoder schematic]

Hi, i want to build an encoder schematic using zener diode, so the input voltage from encoder can more than 5V (using zener 5.1V), if the input voltage from encoder 0V, voltage to uC is 0V, if the input voltage more than 5V (24V for example), the voltage is limited by zener and it will be 5.1V to uC. But, if the input voltage from encoder is unconnected, i want this uC pin is not floating, so i decide to use pull-up resistor to VCC (5V). When i simulate this schematic, i see a negative voltage on R2 resistor which mean current flow to VCC when the input voltage from encoder is 24V, is that ok if current flow to VCC?

Sorry if my english is not good. Thanks.

Comment: Why i got -1 vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It *might* be ok to have current flowing into your 5V supply from the encoder, depending on your power supply and the current consumed by rest of your circuit, but why not rather use a 4.7V zener instead?

4.7V is plenty close enough to 5V for any microcontroller to consider it a 'high' input and you'll never have to worry about current into your 5V supply.

Comment: Hi brhans, it's a good idea..i had simulate using 4.7 zener diode, and there is no current flow to VCC.. I will try 4.7Z configuration then.

Answer (score 0):

Current flow from the 24V encoder to the 5V normal supply is not necessarily a problem by itself, but it could be if this is all that's connected to it.

Basically, if there's enough load to require more current than your configuration supplies in this way, then there will still be current flowing out of the VCC supply.  It's just less than when the encoder is off.  No problems there.

The problem comes when the total load takes less current and so there's a net flow into the VCC supply.  Most regulated supplies will only hold the load up, not down, and will simply allow their outputs to rise to whatever voltage causes equal current from encoder to load, or zero into or out of VCC.  Depending on how high it gets, this may or may not damage something inside the VCC supply.  A very few may actually regulate in both directions (assume you *don't* have one of these unless specifically marked or proven otherwise), and so they'd be fine.

Comment: Hi AaronD...So, you mean it depend on the load? the uC?

Comment: It depends on the total load that is connected to VCC.  When the uC is powered from there, it's included; when it's powered from the encoder, it's not.  Electronic analysis is often iterative: What happens in this case?  What about that case?  How about something else?  Each of those is a separate analysis that follows the same rules, and *all* of them must be acceptable before approving the design.